# How to parse ISO8601 dates with linux date command

Tags: shell-script, date

I'm trying to use the date command to generate a file timestamp that the date command itself can interpret.  However, the date command does not seem to like its own output, and I am not sure how to work around this.  Case in point:

```
sh-4.2$ date
Fri Jan  3 14:22:19 PST 2014
sh-4.2$ date +%Y%m%dT%H%M
20140103T1422
sh-4.2$ date -d "20140103T1422"
Thu Jan  2 23:22:00 PST 2014
```

date appears to be interpreting the string with an offset of 15 hours.  Are there any known workarounds for this?

Edit: this is not an issue of display:

```
sh-4.2$ date +%s
1388791096
sh-4.2$ date +%Y%m%dT%H%M
20140103T1518
sh-4.2$ date -d 20140103T1518 +%s
1388737080
sh-4.2$ python
Python 3.3.3 (default, Nov 26 2013, 13:33:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1388737080 - 1388791096
-54016
>>> 54016/3600
15.004444444444445
>>>
```

It's still off by 15 hours when displayed as a unix timestamp.

#### EDIT #1

Maybe I should pose this question a little differently.  Say I have a list of ISO8601 basic timestamps of the form:

- YYYYMMDDThhmm
- YYYYMMDDThhmmss

What is the simplest way to convert them to the corresponding Unix timestamps?

For example:

```
- 20140103T1422   = 1388787720
- 20140103T142233 = 1388787753
```

Comment: @drewbenn I cannot have any special characters in the timestamp.  Just numbers and letters.  So no, I can't do that, unfortunately.

Comment: @sim TZ is not set, but /etc/localtime is linked.

Comment: You're killing me, is this your final question? 8-)

Comment: `20140103T1518` is not valid ISO 8601, it misses the timezone part

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You ask for "known workarounds."  Here is a simple one:

```
$ date -d "$(echo 20140103T1422 | sed 's/T/ /')"
Fri Jan  3 14:22:00 PST 2014
```

This uses `sed` to replace "T" with a space.  The result is a format that `date` understands.

If we add seconds onto the ISO8601 date, then `date` requires more changes:

```
$ date -d "$(echo 20140103T142211 | sed -r 's/(.*)T(..)(..)(..)/\1 \2:\3:\4/')"
Fri Jan  3 14:22:11 PST 2014
```

In the above, `sed` replaces the "T" with a space and also separates HHMMSS into HH:MM:SS.

Comment: Works for me if the + is deleted.  However, it doesn't work for second precision timestamps, only minute precision.

Comment: @alex.forencich Answer updated with seconds precision.  Let me know if the seconds format that I chose is not the one you need.

Answer (score 16):

The [coreutils info docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items.html) says that ISO 8601 "extended format" is supported.

You'll need to add hyphens, colons, and a `+%z` to make it work.

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
2014-01-03T16:08:23-0800
$ date -d 2014-01-03T16:08:23-0800
Fri Jan  3 16:08:23 PST 2014
```

---

To answer your second part of the question...

Since the date format only contains numbers and symbols, you could replace each symbol with a unique letter, e.g. using `tr`

```
$ ts="$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" | tr -- '-:+' 'hcp')"; echo "$ts"
2014h01h03T16c18c04h0800
$ date -d "$(echo "$ts" | tr -- 'hcp' '-:+')"
Fri Jan  3 16:18:04 PST 2014
```

Or you could parse it using the `T` and the `-` or `+` as separators, e.g. using shell `${var%word}` and `${var#word}` expansion

```
$ ts="$(date +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z")"; echo "$ts"
20140103T162228-0800
$ date=${ts%T*}; time=${ts#*T}
etc.
```

or using `bash` regular expression matching

```
$ ts="$(date +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z")"; echo "$ts"
20140103T165611-0800
$ [[ "$ts" =~ (.*)(..)(..)T(..)(..)(..)(.....) ]]
$ match=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]}")
$ Y=${match[1]}; m=${match[2]}; d=${match[3]}; H=${match[4]}; M=${match[5]}; S=${match[6]}; z=${match[7]}
$ date -d "$Y-$m-$d"T"$H:$M:$S$z"
Fri Jan  3 16:56:11 PST 2014
```

or Perl, Python, etc. etc.

Comment: The timestamp can't have any special characters in it.  Do you know of a good way to add those back in automatically?

Comment: The bash regex approach here met my needs - nice way to parse the string.

Answer (score 8):

GNU coreutils have only supported [ISO 8601 dates](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items.html#Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items) as input since [version 8.13](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS?id=c7fca77515cc0c55f2c47c9f18c313aaef80922c) (released on 2011-09-08). You must be using an older version.

Under older versions, you need to replace the `T` by a space. Otherwise it is interpreted as a [US military time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones).

Even under recent versions, only the fully punctuated form is recognized, not the basic format with only digits and a `T` in the middle.

```
# Given a possibly abbreviated ISO date $iso_date...
date_part=${iso_date%%T*}
if [ "$date_part" != "$iso_date" ]; then
  time_part=${abbreviated_iso_date#*T}
  case ${iso_date#*T} in
    [!0-9]*) :;;
    [0-9]|[0-9][0-9]) time_part=${time_part}:00;;
    *)
      hour=${time_part%${time_part#??}}
      minute=${time_part%${time_part#????}}; minute=${minute#??}
      time_part=${hour}:${minute}:${time_part#????};;
  esac
else
  time_part=
fi
date -d "$date_part $time_part"
```

Answer (score 2):

I did notice this note in the man page for `date`.

```
DATE STRING
      The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string
      such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"  or  "2004-02-29
      16:21:42"  or  even  "next Thursday".  A date string may contain 
      items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of
      week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string 
      indicates the beginning of the day.  The date  string  format
      is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully described 
      in the info documentation.
```

It isn't conclusive but it doesn't explicitly show a time format string that includes the `T` as you're attempting, for [ISO 8601]. As [@Gilles answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107773/7453) indicated, the support of [ISO 8601 in GNU CoreUtils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items.html#Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items) is relatively new.

#### Re-formatting the string

You can use Perl to reformulate your string.

*Example:*

```
$ date -d "$(perl -pe 's/(.*)T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1 $2:$3:$4/' \
    <<<"20140103T142233")"
Fri Jan  3 14:22:33 EST 2014
```

You can make this handle both strings that include seconds and those that do not.

*20140103T1422:*

```
$ date -d "$(perl -pe 's/^(.*)T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/$1 $2:$3:$4/ || \
     s/^(.*)T(\d{2})(\d{2})$/$1 $2:$3:00/' <<<"20140103T1422")"
Fri Jan  3 14:22:00 EST 2014
```

*20140103T142233:*

```
$ date -d "$(perl -pe 's/^(.*)T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/$1 $2:$3:$4/ || \
     s/^(.*)T(\d{2})(\d{2})$/$1 $2:$3:00/' <<<"20140103T142233")"
Fri Jan  3 14:22:33 EST 2014
```

Comment: @alex.forencich - an alternative command that will handle both time formats. Do me a favor and delete the comments above that are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page of date, the format that you output is not the same as what `date` expects as input. This is what the man page says:

```
date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
```

So you could do it like this:

```
# date +%m%d%H%M%Y
010402052014
# date 010402052014
Sat Jan  4 02:05:00 EAT 2014
```

Because in the variables that are used to define the output string, `+%m%d%H%M%Y` would be equal to what it expects as input.

Comment: Then can you provide a command to map an ISO8601 format date into what date requires?  The actual stored timestamps have to be in ISO8601 format so they can be sorted by date.